# How to up Vagrant with hashicorp/precise64 box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I started learning Vagrant and I'm trying to up vagrant machine with `hashicorp/precise64` box. I've installed VirtualBox 5.1 on Gentoo and I emerged Vagrant from Gentoo repository. I executed following command in terminal:

```
pecan@tux ~/vagrant_getting_started $ vagrant box add hashicorp/precise64
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'hashicorp/precise64'
    box: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/precise64
This box can work with multiple providers! The providers that it
can work with are listed below. Please review the list and choose
the provider you will be working with.

1) hyperv
2) virtualbox
3) vmware_fusion

Enter your choice: 2
==> box: Adding box 'hashicorp/precise64' (v1.1.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/hashicorp/boxes/precise64/versions/1.1.0/providers/virtualbox.box
==> box: Successfully added box 'hashicorp/precise64' (v1.1.0) for 'virtualbox'!
pecan@tux ~/vagrant_getting_started $ nano Vagrantfile 
pecan@tux ~/vagrant_getting_started $ vagrant up
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

and I got above error when I tried to up Vagrant machine.

**Vagrantfile** content:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # The most common configuration options are documented and commented below.
  # For a complete reference, please see the online documentation at
  # https://docs.vagrantup.com.

  # Every Vagrant development environment requires a box. You can search for
  # boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "base"

  # Disable automatic box update checking. If you disable this, then
  # boxes will only be checked for updates when the user runs
  # `vagrant box outdated`. This is not recommended.
  # config.vm.box_check_update = false

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  # NOTE: This will enable public access to the opened port
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine and only allow access
  # via 127.0.0.1 to disable public access
  # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network "public_network"

  # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
  # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
  # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
  # argument is a set of non-required options.
  # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

  # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
  # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
  # Example for VirtualBox:
  #
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
     vb.gui = true

     # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "1024"
  end
  #
  # View the documentation for the provider you are using for more
  # information on available options.

  # Enable provisioning with a shell script. Additional provisioners such as
  # Puppet, Chef, Ansible, Salt, and Docker are also available. Please see the
  # documentation for more information about their specific syntax and use.
  # config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  #   apt-get update
  #   apt-get install -y apache2
  # SHELL

  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  end
end
```

`vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` command returns the below error:

```
pecan@tux ~/vagrant_getting_started $ vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

Vagrant could not detect VirtualBox! Make sure VirtualBox is properly installed.
Vagrant uses the `VBoxManage` binary that ships with VirtualBox, and requires
this to be available on the PATH. If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable.
```

I'm counting for help!

Comment: Did you try `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` as it says in the error?

Comment: Yes, still got error. See on edited question.

Comment: "If VirtualBox is installed, please find the
`VBoxManage` binary and add it to the PATH environmental variable."

Comment: VBoxManage is located in `/usr/bin`. PATH environmental variable is equals to `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/5.4.0:/home/pecan/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/bin`.

Comment: `pecan@tux ~/vagrant_getting_started $ VBoxManage` returns `bash: /usr/bin/VBoxManage: Permission denied`. Is definitely a good idea is running Vagrant machines as root because I'm not sure.

Comment: What are the permissions on VBoxManage? `ls -l /usr/bin/VBoxManage`

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/VBoxManage` returned `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Sep 23 04:11 /usr/bin/VBoxManage -> /usr/lib64/virtualbox/VBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vagrantfile` is wrong, it does not contain the correct box information

1. You can remove the whole folder all together and start with `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` which will create a correct Vagrantfile, then you can run `vagrant up` (virtual box should be the default provider if not run `vagrant up --provider virtualbox`)
2. Fix the `Vagrantfile` and replace

   ```
   config.vm.box = "base"
   ```

   with

   ```
   config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
   ```

   Then you can run `vagrant up` and it will work.